# Access class from Android service

Tags: android, android-service

I'm making a small server monitor application, I have a service that will run in the background to check for connection regularly and then if there's any lost or regained connection update server object in a list. However the list is inside a class I made and named ServerListProvider. This is not an activity so my question is, can a service running in the background when the main activity is paused still access and run calls to the serverListProvider class or will the activity have to be running for that to happen?

if it can't acces it when the activity is paused, will making it an internal class in the service work?

Comment: if the class you are trying to access is not an activity and the class is withing the same package of your service, then it will work.